# Is it possible to make a class from bpy.type to implement an abstract class?

Tags: python, interface, add-on, grease-pencil

Here is my problem:

I'm making a Class A. This Class A, has some common functionality that I need to also add to another class (bpy.types.GPencilLayer).

Since that functionality is going to be common, I thought about implementing it using some kind of interface (abstract class (since python dont have interfaces)).

The thing I can make my Class A to implement that abstract class. But what about an alrady existing Blender class? Would it be possible to implement that abstract class in the GPencilLayer type?

Thank you so much.

Comment: AFAIK Blender custom types don't support inheritance, but they can support polymorphism. Inherit from `bpy.types.GPencilLayer` AND `A`

Comment: Didn't thought about that, I think it could solve some of my problems. Thank you much @Gorgious, always helpful 